# Linear regression with inequality constraint in Java

Tags: algorithms, optimization, linear-algebra, java

I haven't been doing math in years and I'm facing the following problem. I'm trying to implement in Java a linear regression under a set of inequality constraints. Sorry in advance for all the approximations while trying to formulate this problem...

More precisely, I have a linear function $f_\Theta:R^n->R$ defined as such: $f_\Theta(X) = \theta_0 + \theta_1x_1+ \theta_0x_2+... \theta_nx_n$, with  $\Theta$ a (n+1) vector.

My aim is to $\min_\Theta \sum_{i}||f_\Theta(X_i)-Y_i||^2$ under the constraint that $f_\Theta(X_i)-Y_i < 0$ for a maximum of $i$ (I wish I could avoid to take into account "obvious" outliers in my observations)

So, bottom line, I'm looking for the linear regression that will act as the "best fit" providing a lower bound for most/all the observations.

How can I do that ? I've been looking for a Java Library that would implement such a thing. I known the [Apache Common Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/) package and I also found this [Flanagan](https://www.ee.ucl.ac.uk/~mflanaga/java/Regression.html) library, but it does not seem to address this.

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Programming is offtopic here. I don't know if [scicomp.SE] wants to have such questions; if not, [SO] is the place.

Comment: FWIW, Java is most certainly *not* the correct tool for numerical algorithms.

Comment: Hi Raphael, what would you advice me to do ? Because there is a mathematical part I would like to understand as well as an implementation part too. Posting this on stack overflow, I'm afraid I will have only people trying to focus on the programming  part. Thanks

Comment: Sounds like [scicomp.SE] might be your place! I can migrate your question there. Do you want to ask in their chat whether your question would be welcome first?

Comment: Looks like you are right. Yes, could you please move my question there if you can ? Thanks a lot !